# Extract hard linked backup data from file server with rsync to exFAT file system

Tags: backup, rsync, apple, hardlink, time-machine

I need to gradually extract all data of the specific directory from Time Machine backup so:

- it fits the destination drive size
- it has no hard links because destination volume file system is exFAT
- it's easy to access data by hand from Windows without Crapple's obsolete software.

I have an Apple laptop with macOS, a Windows laptop with Windows and a virtual machine with macOS. So I'm using Terminal.

The backup is stored in `.sparsebundle` file that is accessible from Finder via `afp://10.0.1.1` (or SMB) and can be mounted from Finder as a volume called `Time Machine Backups`.

The backup's file structure inside is this:

```
Backups.backupdb/MacBook Air/2013-01-01-000000/Macintosh HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop
├───Directory1
│   ├───File1.txt
│   └───File2.txt
├───Directory2
│   ├───File3.txt
│   └───File4.txt
├───File5.txt
└───File6.txt
Backups.backupdb/MacBook Air/2014-01-01-000000/Macintosh HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop
├───Directory1 (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File1.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File2.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   └───File7.txt
├───Directory2 (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File3.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File4.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   └───File8.txt
├───File5.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
├───File6.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
└───File9.txt
Backups.backupdb/MacBook Air/2015-01-01-000000/Macintosh HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop
├───Directory1 (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File1.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File2.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File7.txt (hard link to 2014-01-01-000000)
│   └───File10.txt
├───Directory2 (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File3.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File4.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
│   ├───File8.txt (hard link to 2014-01-01-000000)
│   └───File11.txt
├───File5.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
├───File6.txt (hard link to 2013-01-01-000000)
├───File9.txt (hard link to 2014-01-01-000000)
└───File12.txt
```

The file structure I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
/Volumes/My Passport/MacBook Air/Desktop/2013-01-01-000000/
├───Directory1
│   ├───File1.txt
│   └───File2.txt
├───Directory2
│   ├───File3.txt
│   └───File4.txt
├───File5.txt
└───File6.txt
/Volumes/My Passport/MacBook Air/Desktop/2014-01-01-000000/
├───Directory1
│   └───File7.txt
├───Directory2
│   └───File8.txt
└───File9.txt
/Volumes/My Passport/MacBook Air/Desktop/2015-01-01-000000/
├───Directory1
│   └───File10.txt
├───Directory2
│   └───File11.txt
└───File12.txt
```

I can extract *entire* data with `rsync` (as advised in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230392)) but it won't respect hard links `-H` switch. That results in all the hard linked files copied to each folder all over again no matter if destination file system is exFAT (which doesn't support hardlinks) or HFS+ (which supports hardlinks):

```
cd /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Backups/Backups.backupdb/MacBook\ Air
for F in *; do rsync --progress --ignore-existing -avz -H $F/Macintosh\ HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop /Volumes/My\ Passport/MacBook\ Air/Desktop/$F; done
```

Somebody [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202430/how-to-copy-a-directory-recursively-using-hardlinks-for-each-file#comment409012_202431) "Be aware that hard links do not work across separate filesystem mounts." — maybe that's why it doesn't do what I need. And even if this worked it would leave a ton of hard links in "latest" backup folders which is not what I need after all.

I have also read [this blog article](http://web.archive.org/web/20190207132201/http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html) on using `rsync` `--link-dest=` switch:

```
rsync -avz --progress --link-dest=PATHTO/$PREVIOUSBACKUP $SOURCE $CURRENTBACKUP
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use `--link-dest=` switch for my case: what should I use for `$PREVIOUSBACKUP` to link to each backup date's folder? For instance, if I use `2013-01-01-000000` as `$PREVIOUSBACKUP` location, it won't work correctly and `rsync` will look for files to hard link to only in `2013-01-01-000000`… Should I manually get folder list for all dates and write separate command with correct `--link-dest=` for each folder? Whatever it is, that won't cut it for me as I need no hard links to be there as exFAT doesn't support this feature.

So I came up with a plan I need some critique and some help with:

1. Copy very first backup (that has no hard links) of the folder I need, i.e. `Backups.backupdb/MacBook Air/2013-01-01-000000/Macintosh HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop`
2. Generate a TXT file with this list of folders of all "other" dates incremental backup took place:

   Backups.backupdb/MacBook Air/2014-01-01-000000/Macintosh HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop
   Backups.backupdb/MacBook Air/2015-01-01-000000/Macintosh HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop
3. For each of the "other" incremental backups generate a separate TXT file with the list of unique files that was added to the latest folder (as advised in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15718)), i.e.:

> Since Time Machine uses hard links to store unmodified files (and
> directories), this would mean that changed files in the latest backup
> will have a link count of 1 since they are unique. Use this together
> with find to generate a listing

```
cd /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Backups/Backups.backupdb/MacBook\ Air
find 2014-01-01-000000/Macintosh\ HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop -type f -links 1 -print
find 2015-01-01-000000/Macintosh\ HD/Users/TimApple/Desktop -type f -links 1 -print
```

4. Use `rsync` to copy only files from TXT gathered in step 3 using `--files-from=` switch as briefly described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349398/copy-structure-of-dirs-with-files-from-file-txt#comment2306827_1349398).

I'm not that familiar with Terminal so please advise if my plan is OK and please help with the steps if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend a custom script to transform how backups are structured and stored. Especially being new to working in the terminal. Too much risk of data loss, either the inversion of how the directories are stored, or the deduplication part.

If you wish to platform migrate off of macOS, restore all the needed data, at the desired point in time. Perhaps attach the SMB mount to Windows, and manually copy one point in time from Explorer.  Or, restore to macOS, create a zip archive with the relevant files, transfer that over and extract.  As Time Machine is not a Windows thing, start a different backup procedure on the new platform. Keep the Time Machine backups around in case more restores are needed.

---

rsync is capable of maintaining hard links that exist in the source. Even if the target is on a different file system. However this won't work for a couple reasons:

extFAT target does not support links.

Your proposed script loops over the date stamps and runs a rsync command for each. The hard links between dates are now not in the source set of one rsync command. Even if the target did support hard links, `rsync --hard-links` alone will not make use of them to deduplicate.

`rsync --link-dest=DIR`  checks for duplicate files in DIR and hard links them to the destination. Note the is is rsync doing the de-duplication, not Time Machine. This won't work when the target does not support links, of course.

`rsync  --compare-dest=DIR` behaves differently but could be an alternative when links are not available. When a duplicate exists in DIR, the file is not transferred. Reduces space used, but now you need to manually look at previous dates to find all files.  In theory useful: copy all of the latest tree, then use --compare-dest with it to create older  sparse backups.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into it, John, I find your suggestion of `--compare-dest=` useful and will mark it as an answer if it helps (cannot upvote yet because of low reputation). I will probably update the question since it appears hard link count for unique files in step 3 of my plan doesn't work as I expected and isn't helpful. Currently I stopped at extracting latest backup and comparing each earlier backup manually using SearchMyFiles duplicate files search. This takes a lot of time because I have to download each backup. So `--compare-dest=` should tremendously improve workflow…

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like `rsync --compare-dest=` won't cut it because of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370598) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104185/how-do-you-compare-two-folders-and-copy-the-difference-to-a-third-folder/104265#comment956604_104265). Oh well, manual way it is.